# Retrieve specific number of tweets using search keyword

Tags: python, tweets

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time


s=raw_input('string');

try:
    file = open('keyword.txt', 'r')
    keyword=file.read()


    ckey ='CONSUMER KEY'
    csecret ='CONSUMER SECRET'
    atoken ='ACCESS TOKEN'
    asecret='ACCESS SECRET'

    class listener(StreamListener):

        def on_data(self, data):


           # print data

            tweet=data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
            print (tweet)
            print ('\n')
            saveThis=tweet
            saveFile =open('projectdatabase.csv','a')
            saveFile.write(saveThis )
            saveFile.write('\n')
            saveFile.close()
            return True

        def on_error(self, status):
            print (status)


            auth=OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
            auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
            twitterStream=Stream(auth, listener())
            twitterStream.filter(track=[keyword])

except Exception:
```

Comment: Everyone wants help, that's why they post questions. If you want help, you'll need to be more specific as to what you want help *with*. Does the code not work? How does it not work? What should it do if it does work? What happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your Question needs to be more descriptive,however if you want to obtain specific number of tweets using search...you can refer this example

import tweepy
import csv #Import csv
import json
import codecs
import datetime

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

#Access tokens 
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('#######', '#######')
auth.set_access_token('########', '######')

api = tweepy.API(auth)
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('result1234.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
f = codecs.open('abc.csv',encoding='utf-8', mode='a')

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, 
                    q="Interstellar", 
                    since="2015-01-30", 
                    until="2015-02-01",


                lang="en").items(10000):
#Write a row to the csv file/ I use encode utf-8
print tweet;
csvWriter.writerow([tweet])
```